# Error when opening txt file in Python

Tags: python

I have to work with a txt file and to do that I used the following code:

```
inputFile = open("C:/Abaqus_JOBS/Job-M1-3_4.inp", "r") #CAE INPUT FILE
```

However I get this error when I ran this line in a specific application for running python scripts available in another program. I don't get any error when I ran it in Spyder.

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I don't have a clue why this error occurs....

EDIT:
lines of code until line in question

```
import os
from os import *
from abaqus import *
from odbAccess import *
from abaqusConstants import *
import time
import itertools

os.chdir('C:\\Abaqus_JOBS')

LCKf = 'C:\\Abaqus_JOBS\\Job-M1-3_2.lck'
STAf = 'C:\\Abaqus_JOBS\\Job-M1-3_2.sta'

def get_num_part(s):
    for i in xrange(len(s)):
        if s[i:].isdigit():
            return s[i:]
    return ''

if not path.exists(LCKf):
    time.sleep(1)
while path.exists(LCKf) and path.isfile(LCKf) and access(LCKf, R_OK):
    variableX = 0
else:
    odb = openOdb(path='Job-M1-3_2.odb')
#get CF
#session.odbs[name].steps[name].frames[i].FieldOutput
    myAssembly = odb.rootAssembly    
    myAssemblyName = odb.rootAssembly.name

    nsteps=len(odb.steps.values())

    step1 = odb.steps.values()[nsteps-1]
    step1Name = odb.steps.values()[nsteps-1].name

    myInstanceName = odb.rootAssembly.instances.values()[0].name

    dCF3=[]
    dCF3v=[]
    coordFv=[]
    fileData = [] #array with the input file
    nodes = [] #array with the content of *NODES

    inputFile = open("C:/Abaqus_JOBS/Job-M1-3_4.inp", "r") #CAE INPUT FILE
    #fileData = variable with all the lines of the inp file
    for line in inputFile:
        fileData.append([x.strip() for x in line.split(',')])
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Abaqus_JOBS/results.py", line 47, in <module>
    inputFile = open("C:/Abaqus_JOBS/Job-M1-3_4.inp", "r") #CAE INPUT FILE
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: Please give your full stack trace, and all the code you ran - it's highly likely the error is not happening on this line. (As a side note, when opening files it's best to use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4).)

Comment: Which application? This error obviously was not created by CPython on the line you gave, so the specific application is important.

Comment: You didn't do anything to shadow the builtin open did you?

Comment: Those `from ... import *` lines are a massive red-flag. It's likely one of them has an `open()` function that is shadowing the built-in. It's extremely rare that `import *` is a good idea - you should only do it occasionally with libraries specifically designed to be loaded like that.

Comment: @Lattyware: OK, I'll change these lines. Thanks for the tip. I'll reply soon with an update

Comment: Ah, good old `os.open`..

Comment: @Lattyware: I closed the main program and reopened it... it now works.... strange I think. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the

```
from os import *
```

You're importing all `os` stuff in the global namespace, including [`os.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open). Don't do this.

The second argument, *flags*, is defined as integer constants while you're providing a single-character string `r`.  This is basically what [DSM was telling you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402894/error-when-opening-txt-file-in-python#comment23514945_16402894) and what [Lattyware said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402894/error-when-opening-txt-file-in-python#comment23514673_16402894).

`open()` included in Python by default in the global namespace, which you were expecting apparently, is different:

> **Note:** This function is intended for low-level I/O. For normal usage,
>   use the built-in function open(), which returns a “file object” with
>   read() and write() methods (and many more). To wrap a file descriptor
>   in a “file object”, use fdopen().